# Filter pandas dataframe where field is supposedly a timestamp but info() shows non null object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I am trying to push into a database but I get an error message that my primary key constraint is violated:

```
ecom.to_sql('ecom',
            con = engine,
            schema = 'ga_shop',
            index = False,
            if_exists = 'append')
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ecom_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (product_name, dimension3, dimension1)=(Apples, 2019-10-29 19:12:58.83+00, 1572376787423.pgp5jcd7) already exists.
```

I would like to filter dataframe ecom to take a look at these duplicate rows but I am unable to:

```
ecom[(ecom['dimension3'] == '2019-10-29 19:12:58.83+00')]
```

Returns an empty dataframe.

```
ecom.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 82 entries, 14014 to 15002
Data columns (total 15 columns):
dimension1                   82 non-null object
dimension3                   82 non-null object
product_name                 82 non-null object

ecom.head()
              dimension1                     dimension3  ... item_revenue sampling
0  1572337407387.0epe8tn  2019-10-29T04:20:08.119-04:00  ...          0.0    False
1  1572337407387.0epe8tn  2019-10-29T04:20:08.119-04:00  ...          0.0    False
2  1572337407387.0epe8tn  2019-10-29T04:20:08.119-04:00  ...          0.0    False
3  1572337407387.0epe8tn  2019-10-29T04:20:08.119-04:00  ...          0.0    False
4  1572337407387.0epe8tn  2019-10-29T04:20:08.119-04:00  ...          0.0    False
```

Field dimension3 is an iso timestamp that I retreived from an API but it's unclear to me how pandas is storing it since it says '82 non null object' when I check with `ecom.info()`

How can I filter on dimension3, the timestamp, to match that of the error message so that I can see those duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortuantely you have to convert to datetimes before filtering with `utc=True`, because there are different timezones:

```
date = pd.to_datetime('2019-10-29 19:12:58.83+00', utc=True)
df = ecom[pd.to_datetime(ecom['dimension3'], utc=True) == date]
```

Another solution should be convert only string:

```
print (ecom)
              dimension1                        dimension3  item_revenue  \
0  1572337407387.0epe8tn  2019-10-29 04:20:08.119000-04:00           0.0   
1  1572337407387.0epe8tn  2019-10-29 04:20:08.119000-04:00           0.0   
2  1572337407387.0epe8tn  2019-10-29 04:20:08.119000-04:00           0.0   
3  1572337407387.0epe8tn  2019-10-29 04:20:08.119000-04:00           0.0   
4  1572337407387.0epe8tn  2019-10-29 19:12:58.830000+00:00           0.0   

   sampling  
0     False  
1     False  
2     False  
3     False  
4     False <-changed date

print (type(ecom['dimension3'].iat[0]))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

df = ecom[ecom['dimension3'] == pd.to_datetime('2019-10-29 19:12:58.83+00')]
print (df)
              dimension1                        dimension3  item_revenue  \
4  1572337407387.0epe8tn  2019-10-29 19:12:58.830000+00:00           0.0   

   sampling  
4     False
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried your code and got this error message: ````ValueError: Array must be all same time zone...ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

Comment: @DougFir - it means there are different timezones, it is like you need?

Comment: I'm using ISO with timezone offset e.g. from the original data source 2019-10-29T04:20:08.119-04:00

Comment: @DougFir - Can you test now?

Comment: Hi, yes I just tried following your edit and got the same error

Comment: @DougFir - What is your pandas version?

Comment: Hi, `pd.__version__
'0.25.1'`

Comment: Hi, this worked now. Thank you very much. So adding utc flag was the magic trick?

Comment: @DougFir - yop, there is problem with different timezones in same column, so it failed.

Comment: I can see in the original data source two similar timestamps which are being used for the id: `2019-10-29T15:12:58.83-04:00` and `2019-10-29T15:12:58.830-04:00`. So one is 83 and one has 830. After applying your filter I see that pandas sees them as the same, both `2019-10-29T15:12:58.830000-04:00`. I could post another question but just in case you know, is this a conversion of timestamps thing with Pandas? Is there a prescribed way to handle this so that Pandas will continue to see them as distinct values?

Comment: @DougFir - hmmm, hard question, maybe first if check `print (type(ecom['dimension3'].iat[0]))` it return `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>` or not?

Comment: Hi, yes it does return that: `print (type(ecom['dimension3'].iat[0]))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`

Comment: @DougFir - Maybe stupid question - it is not same? Because `830`, `83` is number of miliseconds - `830000`. So it should be same.

Comment: I guess it could be. Actually I don't really know. I will check with our developers

Comment: @DougFir - OK, super, please let me know it, because I am not 1000% sure ;) Thank you.

Comment: I will update here if I find out! Thank you for your help

Comment: OK, you were right they are in fact showing the exact same time, just with different padding on the milliseconds part